# Using Plesk to setup MySQL

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, mysql, plesk

Having trouble getting my mysql up and running on a new virtual server.  The host gave me Plesk and I think MySQL is installed but I can't seem to access it.

I keep getting this:

```
 mysql -u admin -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

How do I make sure its running properly?
How do I reset the root password? (I have root access to the server)

Answer (score 0):

If you want admin access to the MySQL you need to do:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Answer (score 0):

Karlson's right in the sane world outside of Plesk... in Plesk by default mysql `root` is renamed to `admin`.

It's supposed to sync passwords with your admin password, but life is never that simple. Try:

```
mysql -uadmin -p `cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow`
```

(a cheat's way of logging in, the .psa.shadow bit gets whatever the mysql password is and uses it. Go security!)

If that gives you a 1045 error, go down to the bit about that [on this page](https://support.vpsit.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=48). If it works and logs you in...

- You can find the Plesk mysql password which it used, unencypted, by opening that `/etc/psa/.psa.shadow` file.
- You can see your Plesk admin password unencrypted on screen with `/usr/local/psa/bin/admin --show-password` (go security!). In theory my understanding is that the two passwords should be the same... getting them to actually sync is a separate issue.